# How can I link my contacts?

Tags: contacts, sync, outlook

I have two Gmail accounts and an Outlook account. How can I sync my contact lists and link them together so I don't have to manually add/update the same contact in each?

Answer (score 2):

You need a third party tool to sync your Outlook and Gmail contact books together.  [Google offers a tool you can download to sync](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gappssync), and there are others out there you can download/buy if you don't like theirs.